# xcode - stop audio files from playing over each other

Tags: ios, xcode, audio, avaudioplayer

So I am new to xcode and programming in general.  I am creating a simple soundboard and I am running into an issue.  What I want to do is stop the current audio from playing when a different audio button is selected. Then have the stopped audio reset itself and be ready to start playing from the beginning when pressed again.  I had added a stop() to my code and it would stop() the audio from playing but when I would try to restart it, I discovered that the audio just paused, and continued from the where it stopped.

Can anyone provide me with the code set that I need to fix this, and if not can anyone point me in the direction of a good tutorial that can lead me down the right path.  I looked at the apple Audio documentation and unfortunately I got lost.

My code is as follows.

```
var SoundPlayer1:AVAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
var SoundPlayer2:AVAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
var SoundPlayer3:AVAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let FileLocation1 = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Audio1", ofType: "mp3")
    let FileLocation2 = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Audio2", ofType: "mp3")
    let FileLocation3 = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Audio3", ofType: "mp3")

    do {
        SoundPlayer1 = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: FileLocation1!))
        SoundPlayer2 = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: FileLocation2!))
        SoundPlayer3 = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: FileLocation3!))

        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient)
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
    }

    catch {
        print(error)
    }

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func catButton(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    SoundPlayer1.play()
}

@IBAction func pigButton(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    SoundPlayer2.play()
}

@IBAction func pigButton(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    SoundPlayer3.play()
}
```

Comment: call stop() function before playing second audio. Write this code in pigButton  function SoundPlayer1.stop() SoundPlayer2.play(). Here you need to check if audio1 is playing then only call  SoundPlayer1.stop() function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a bit of Swift logic you can carry out to check if any other of the players are playing and then stop them!

```
  // Make sure all audio playback times are reset
  func resetAllAudioTime(){
    SoundPlayer1.currentTime = 0.0;
    SoundPlayer2.currentTime = 0.0;
    SoundPlayer3.currentTime = 0.0;
  }

  IBAction func catButton(_ sender: AnyObject) {

  // Check SoundPlayer2 and stop if playing 
  if(SoundPlayer2.playing){
    SoundPlayer2.pause();
  }

  // Check SoundPlayer3 and stop if playing
  if(SoundPlayer3.playing){
    SoundPlayer3.pause();
  }

  // Reset all playback times to start of file
  resetAllAudioTime();

  // Play audio file
  SoundPlayer1.play()
}

@IBAction func pigButton(_ sender: AnyObject) {

  // Check SoundPlayer1 and stop if playing 
  if(SoundPlayer1.playing){
    SoundPlayer1.pause();
  }

  // Check SoundPlayer3 and stop if playing
  if(SoundPlayer3.playing){
    SoundPlayer3.pause();
  }

  // Reset all playback times to start of file
  resetAllAudioTime();

  // Play audio file
  SoundPlayer2.play()
}

@IBAction func pigButton(_ sender: AnyObject) {

  // Check SoundPlayer1 and stop if playing 
  if(SoundPlayer1.playing){
    SoundPlayer1.pause();
  }

  // Check SoundPlayer2 and stop if playing
  if(SoundPlayer2.playing){
    SoundPlayer2.pause();
  }

  // Reset all playback times to start of file
  resetAllAudioTime();

  // Play audio file
  SoundPlayer3.play()
}
```

**Note:** *This code is untested but should work. See the [AVAudioPlayer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudioplayer) docs for any further help.*

You will see that rather than calling the `AVAudioPlayer.stop()` method, I have used the `AVAudioPlayer.pause()` and then reset the playback time to the start. If you read the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudioplayer) it states calling the `AVAudioPlayer.stop()` method:

> ```
> func stop()
> ```
>
> Stops playback and undoes the setup needed for playback.

Therefore, calling pause and resetting the time doesn't keep undoing the setup needed for playback (should be more efficient!).

I hope this helps! :-)

Comment: WoodyDev Thank you for the help.  Please see my solution below.

Answer (score 0):

WoodyDev, thank you for the info it was clean and easy to understand.  I was able to fix my issue with two functions.

```
    func stopAll() {
        SoundPlayer1.stop()
        SoundPlayer2.stop() 
}   
    func resetAudioTime() {
        SoundPlayer1.currentTime = 0.0;
        SoundPlayer2.currentTime = 0.0; 
}    
    @IBAction func catButton(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        stopAll();<br/>
        resetAudioTime();<br/>
        SoundPlayer1.play()
}
```